# Get back Request Body within ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

For logging purposes, I am trying to monitor the requests being made through a WebAPI. I have created and I am looking for a way to get back the body sent through in a request after the request has been fulfilled and responded to. I am trying to do this through using a `ActionFilter` but thus far have failed in reading the body from the request.

Can anybody give some advice how I may access this information?

For context I am trying to do this within this code:

```
    public class LoggingActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var test = actionExecutedContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return base.OnActionExecutedAsync(actionExecutedContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

I have tried reading back the `Content` on the `actionExecutedContext` variable in order to get back the body but have found this to return just blank so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're just dealing with request body so don't need to use `OnActionExecutedAsync` method, you can just override `OnActionExecuting` like this,

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)

   {
       var test = (actionContext.Request.Content as ObjectContent).Value.ToString();
       // your logging code here
   }
```

Another option available in WebAPI is `DelegatingHandler`. if you want to log just request body then override `SendAsync` method,

```
public class ApiLogHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
 protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,          
                                               CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
   var requestBody = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   // your logging code here
   return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
 }
}
```

If you decided to choose `DelegatingHandler` then you need to register that handler to `Global message handlers`.

Comment: I've tried out the OnActionExecuting command but had no luck, it throws a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error. The idea with the delegating handler does work but I was hoping to do it after the request has been fulfilled. Would this be possible?

Comment: After changing my function over to using a non Async function as you suggested, I was able to get back the body as I wanted through `actionExecutedContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`. Thanks!